# How can I tell if these two small samples (n=24) are significantly different?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, t-test

Here's the two groups to make it easy for you guys. I've tried using R. I can reject significant difference at the 95th confidence interval (they slightly overlap) but a t test in R is telling me they are significantly different. I'm confused. I'll put it in an easy format so you can just copy and paste it into R. n = 24 for both groups.

```r
    x1 <- c(0.041583333, 0.023583333, 0.033783333, 0.028883333, 
            0.029683333, 0.030683333, 0.027083333, 0.032183333, 
            0.037083333, 0.035683333, 0.035783333, 0.034883333, 
            0.032383333, 0.039083333, 0.036083333, 0.032083333, 
            0.034983333, 0.030583333, 0.032883333, 0.031383333, 
            0.036283333, 0.033683333,   0.041783333, 0.039383333)
    
    x2 <- c(0.057775,   0.030975,   0.036675,   0.037075,
            0.037375,   0.029275,   0.027875,   0.031275,
            0.034775,   0.034675,   0.041275,   0.044575,
            0.052608333, 0.035208333, 0.025908333,  
            0.050108333, 0.050708333, 0.034008333, 0.040608333, 
            0.035708333, 0.039608333,   0.031008333,    
            0.041008333,    0.044008333)
```

This is what I did for the Confidence Interval calculations (taken from the console):

```r
    > x1mean = mean(x1)        
    > sdx1 = sqrt(var(x1))
    > z = qnorm(1-(0.05/2))
    > n = 24
    > UBx1 = x1mean + ((z*sdx1)/(sqrt(n)))
    > LBx1 = x1mean - ((z*sdx1)/(sqrt(n)))
    > CIx1<- c(LBx1, UBx1)
    > CIx1
    [1] 0.03206154 0.03556346
```

95th Confidence Interval for x2 was calculated same way:

```r
    > x2mean<- mean(x2)
    > sdx2<- sqrt(var(x2))
    > UBx2<- x2mean + ((z*sdx2)/(sqrt(n)))
    > LBx2<- x2mean - ((z*sdx2)/(sqrt(n)))
    > CIx2<- c(LBx2, UBx2)
    > CIx2
    [1] 0.03523397 0.04177437
```

As you can see the upper bound of x1 overlaps with the lower bound of x2 by my calculations.

Also, stripchart shows a high degree of entanglement:

```r
    stripchart(list(G=x1,x2), pch="|", ylim=c(.5,2.5))
```

Comment: I don't think you can conclude that $H_0: \mu_1 =\mu_2$ is not rejected at 5% level against a 2-sided alternative from the fact that their separate 95% CI overlap. You could conclude that from the fact that a 95% CI for $\mu_1-\mu_2$ doesn't contain $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Following recommended practice, my default 2-sample t test
is the Welch test, which does not assume equal population variances.
The two-sided test finds a significant difference in population means
with P-value $0.018 < 0.05 = 5\%.$ Furthermore, the 95% CI has
both endpoints negative, so it does not include $0.$ These finidins
are compatible.

```
t.test(x1,x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -2.4789, df = 35.186, p-value = 0.01812
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.0085331538 -0.0008501799
sample estimates:
  mean of x  mean of y 
 0.03381250 0.03850417
```

For the record, a pooled test gives similar results:

```
t.test(x1,x2, var.eq=T)$p.val
[1] 0.01690508
t.test(x1,x2, var.eq=T)$conf.int
[1] -0.0085013031 -0.0008820306
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

There is some association between vectors `x1` and `x2` as you
have presented them.

```
cor(x1,x2)
[1] 0.4193936
```

So I did a paired t test, in case that might be what you intended.
But the paired test rejects and the paired CI does not include $0.$

```
t.test(x1,x2, pair=T)$p.val
[1] 0.005387244

t.test(x1,x2, pair=T)$conf.int
[1] -0.007850498 -0.001532836
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Without any context on the source of these data, I am puzzled what
you are trying to discover from them and what why you found test
results and CI to be contradictory.

*Note:* While `x2` passes a Shapiro-Wilk normality test, its normal probability plot does not look linear.

```
qqnorm(x2, datax=T); qqline(x2, datax=T, col="blue")
```

[image]

```
boxplot(x2, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Bruce! I saw that the Welch t test in R determined that there was statistical significance, but I am trying to determine if there is a PRACTICAL difference between the two groups. I also did a Cohen's D test using the effsize package in R, and it came out with a medium effect. I do not know how to interpret that

Comment: For me, the issue of practical important is up to to what experimenters were looking for. If Cohen's D is your criterion, why are you puzzled by that 'medium effect'? The difference between the sample means is noticeably larger than the standard errors. // I don't want to squelch your curiosity but I still don't know what prompted you to post these data. // Maybe your intuition would change if you changed the units, multiplying everything by 100.

Comment: This is unitless data because they are absorbances on a spectrophotometer that I use in my research laboratory as a grad student in Biochemistry. One of the extra reasons I have a hard time saying things are practically different, although statistically different, is because stripchart analysis (posted in the edits I made above) shows high degree of entanglement to my eyes.

Comment: @Brian You have the effect size. Now it is on your subject matter experts (you might be one of them) to decide if that is important. The means differ by about $0.05$ units. Does that matter to you?

Comment: I'm still wondering about the significant correlation btw `x1` and `x2`. Bootstrapped it (similarly to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59748/understanding-bootstrap-method-for-confidence-interval-of-correlation-coefficien)) and it seems significantly positive. Is it possible there is some kind of pairing between the two?

Comment: @BruceET The data (x1 and x2) are absorbances produced by different antibodies against the same antigen. The absorbances of x1 do not depend on x2 and vice versa. Can you show me what you did with the bootstrapping in an update to your answer above?

Comment: Plan to do bootstrap soon. There is life beyond stackexchange, so can't right now. // Several hours later: See new Answer with bootstrap CIs for $\rho.$

Answer (score 0):

**Confidence Intervals for Population Correlation**

In my main answer to this question, I mentioned that there
may be positive correlation between data vectors `x1` and `x2`.
Comments suggested posting CIs for $\rho.$ I put them in a separate
Answer box because the issue of correlation was not mentioned
in the original question. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59748/understanding-bootstrap-method-for-confidence-interval-of-correlation-coefficien) has additional comments on bootstrapping correlations by @Glen_b.$

First, the traditional Ci for $\rho,$ due to Fisher, is appropriate
for normal data. Because I doubt that `x2` is normal I question
its accuracy. In R, the procedure is `cor.test`. Its test rejects that $\rho = 0$ at the 5% level and its 95% CI is $(0.019, 0.704).$

```
cor.test(x1, x2)

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x1 and x2
t = 2.1669, df = 22, p-value = 0.04134
alternative hypothesis: 
 true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01925435 0.70373157
sample estimates:
       cor 
 0.4193936
```

A simple 95% quantile bootstrap CI for $\rho$ based on
re-sampled pairs is $(0.052, 0.699).$ The bootstrap CIs shown
here do not assume normal data.

```
set.seed(629)
B = 4000;  r.re=numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
 ix = sample(1:24, 24, rep=T)
r.re[i] = cor(x1[ix],x2[ix])
}
CI = quantile(r.re, c(.025,.975)); CI
      2.5%      97.5% 
0.05189491 0.69921598 

hdr = "Bootstrap Dist'n of Sample Correlations"
hist(r.re, prob=T, col="skyblue2", xlab="r", main=hdr)
 abline(v = CI, col="red")
 abline(v = cor(x1,x2))
```

[image]

There are many styles of bootstrapping. This one is deprecated for various reasons,
especially when the bootstrap distribution is skewed, as here.

A style of bootstrapping that does some bias correction
involves re-sampling deviations about the observed sample
correlation $r.$ It gives the CI $(0.140, 0.787)$ for $\rho,$
which I suppose is more accurate.

```
set.seed(629)
r.obs = cor(x1,x2); r.obs
[1] 0.4193936
B = 4000;  d.re=numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
 ix = sample(1:24, 24, rep=T)
 d.re[i] = cor(x1[ix],x2[ix]) - r.obs
 }
UL = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
CI = r.obs - UL;  CI
    97.5%      2.5% 
0.1395712 0.7868922 
hdr = "Bootstrap of Deviations about r"
hist(r.obs - d.re, prob=T, col="skyblue2", xlab="r", main=hdr)
 abline(v=CI, col="red")
 abline(v = r.obs)
```

[image]

> Briefly, the rationale for this method of bootstrapping is as follows.
> If we knew the distribution of $D = r - \rho,$ we could find values $L$ and $U$ that cut probabilities $0.025$ from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of that distribution. Then pivot to
> get the 95% CI $(U - r, L-r)$ for $\rho.$
>
> Not knowing the distribution of $D,$ we temporarily use the observed value $r = r_{obs}$ of the sample correlation for $\rho.$ We re-sample $n$ pairs $(X_{1j},X_{2j})$ with replacement and find the corresponding sample correlation $r^*$ and also $D^* - r^*-r_{obs}.$ .
> Repeating this
> resampling several thousand times, we can get a good idea of the
> distribution of $D.$
>
> Then quantiles $0.025$ and $0.975$ (call them $L^*, U^*)$ of the $D^*$s
> approximate $L$ and $U,$ so that $U^* - r, L^*-r$ is approximately a 95% CI for $\rho.$

All three CIs shown above are consistent with positive correlation
between `x1` and `x2`. Additional comments on methods of
bootstrapping correlations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see the upper bound of x1 overlaps with the lower bound of x2 by my calculations.

If I'm not mistaken, 95% confidence intervals can overlap and still you can regard the difference as significant at alpha 5% from a t-test. Conversely, the intervals defined by +/- 1 standard error may *not* overlap and yet the difference is *not* significant at alpha 5%.

Crawley's [R Book](https://www.cs.upc.edu/%7Erobert/teaching/estadistica/TheRBook.pdf) has a nice explanation of this, search for *least significant difference* (the pdf of the book seems to be available at multiple places).

The least significant difference is:

```
LSD = qt(0.975,df) × standard error of a difference ≈ 2 × se_diff
```

LSD is such that if the intervals overlap the difference is not significant at the given alpha, if they don't overlap they are significant.